# Django 'likes' - ManyToManyField vs new model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm implementing likes on profiles for my website and I'm not sure which would be the best practice, a ManyToManyField like so:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...
    likes = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical = False, null = True)
    ...
```

or just creating a class Like, like so:

```
class Like(models.Model):
    liker = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, related_name='liker')
    liked = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, related_name='liked')
```

Is one of them a better choice than the other? If so, why?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second option is basically what is done internally: a new table is created, which is used to create the links between the entities.

For the first option, you let django do the job for you.

The choice is certainly more about how you want to do the requests. On the second options, you would have to query the `Like` models that match you model, while on the first one, you only have to request the `MyUser`, from which you can access the connections.

Comment: So basically performance-wise and storage-wise they're the same?

Comment: I have no data to prove which one is faster, but I tend to trust that what the Django team has explicitly added is done correctly, and will certainly be more optimized than if I do it myself.

Answer (score 5):

The first option should be preffered. If you need some additional fields to describe the likes, you can still use `through="Likes"` in your `ManyToManyField` and define the model `Likes`.

Manipulating the data entries would be also somewhat more pythonic:

```
# returns an object collection
likes_for_me = MyUser.objects.filter(pk=1).likes
```

instead of:

```
me = MyUser.objects.filter(pk=1)
likes_for_me = Like.objects.filter(liked=me)
```

Comment: To keep code 'pythonic' he always can make a method ```MyUser.likes``` which return queryset with likes related to current ```MyUser``` instance.

But your advise about 'through' option is very useful, thank you!

Comment: @IgorPomaranskiy Yes, you're right, using the `related_name` he can make `MyUser.liked.all()` and still get all likes.

Comment: actually, I meant something like ```def likes(self): return Like.objects.filter(liked=self)```, because ```Like.liked``` probably will become Generic Foreign Key, and there will be some issues with ```related_name```. :)

Answer (score 3):

Second option is more flexible and extensible. For example, you'll probably want to track when like was created (just add `Like.date_created` field). Also you'll probably want to send notification to content author when content was liked. But at first like only (add `Like.cancelled` boolead field and wrap it with some logic...).

So I'll go with separate model.

Answer (score 0):

I think the one you choose totally depends on the one you find easier to implement or better. I tend to always use the first approach, as it is more straightforward and logical, at least to me. I also disagree with Igor on that it's not flexible and extensible, you can also initiate notifications when it happens. If you are going to use the Django rest framework, then I totally suggest using the first method, as the second could be a pain.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    like = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name='post_like')
```

Then in your view, you just do this.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def like(request, id):
    signed_in = request.user
    post = Post.objects.get(id=id)

    if signed_in and post:
        post.like.add(signed_in)
        # For unlike, remove instead of add
        return Response("Successful")
    else:
        return Response("Unsuccessful",  status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Then you can use the response however you like on the front end.